# How to get "object texture coordinates" in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Do someone knows how to use *object texture coordinates* in geometry nodes, like we can do it in the shader editor for materials?

I would like to keep the sampled texture size proportions for the distribution always the same on all objects. Currently the size will be shrinked on non quadratic objects, when I use the UVMap atrribute.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Here's the solution, for everyone interested.

[image]

Comment: Just beat me to it :)  BTW, Blender Guru, in his tutorial, wrongly identifies `position` with the 'Generated' output of the _Texture Coordinate_ node. It's the position, in Object Space, so equivalent to the 'Object' output.