# How can I use the same Noise Texture in Shader Editor to distribute points with Geometry Node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been trying to distribute points on a plane and make the density correspond to the the Noise Texture I am using in the Shader Editor, using the "Generated" texture coordinate output.

I found a guy explaining how to replicate the Generated vector in Geometry Node using a Map Range, (The answer of this question: [Basic Noise Texture maps differently in Geometry Nodes vs Shader Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262888/basic-noise-texture-maps-differently-in-geometry-nodes-vs-shader-editor)) but it still doesn't correspond to my Noise Texture Shader, even tho both of the Noises in Shader and in Geo Node have the exact same parameters.

Actual Preview[image: Actual Preview]Shader Editor Setup[image: Shader Editor Setup]Geometry Node Setup[image: GeometryNode Setup]
I feel like I am missing something obvious, I hope someone can guide me through this little struggle.
(I run Blender 3.2.2)
blend File: [image]

Comment: There is a Texture Panel in the Properties Tab. Try to create the texture there and use that. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/texture_panel.html

Comment: can u link that video where "the guy explaining...."?

Comment: Chris, it's not a video, it's another post on this forum. 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262888/basic-noise-texture-maps-differently-in-geometry-nodes-vs-shader-editor
In his exemple he uses Checker Texture, which works fine when I try it but it doesn't with a Noise Texture and I can't figure the reason why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The guy" would have a working example for you here:

[image]

PS: Sorry, since you unfortunately didn't share your blend file, and I can't tell from the images alone what you did wrong, I can only give you a finished example.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: I was hoping for you to come help me actually, I knew you could easily figure this out when I saw your answer on the other question. Thanks a lot !!! If I link my blend file, could you take a minute to tell me what went wrong ?
Thanks a lot again Mr Quellenform :D

Comment: @Zushi You are welcome! Yes, please upload the file.

Comment: I finally figured out how to do it x') I really appreciate

Comment: @Zushi I figured it out: You put the output *Color* into the *Color Ramp* in your shader, instead of the output *Fac*. thereby in *Geometry Nodes* something else was interpreted.

Comment: I thought you were right, I plugged the Fac of the Noise texture into the Color Ramp of both Shader Editor and Geometry Node, but it didn't work. I figured that you put 0 in the Z scale of the Mapping node in Shader Editor, I didn't noticed it and it worked fine after I corrected that. 
I still don't understand why it works tho haha but thanks a lot for your time ! I'll be careful of that now :D

Comment: @Zushi The _Noise Texture_ creates random values in 3D (unless set to 1D/2D), but your plane is taking just a 2D slice out of it. Since _Texture Coordinate_ > _Generated_ maps an object from 0 to 1 on each axis, the center of geometry is at 0.5/0.5/0.5, so the 2D slice in the material shows the XY noise at a Z = 0.5 (although your plane is infinitely flat), but in _Geometry Nodes_ you see the XY noise at Z = 0. Which means you can either set the _Mapping_ node in the shader to Z = -0.5 to get the same slice as in _Geometry Nodes_ or there you set _From Min_ to Z = 0.5 in the _Map Range_ node.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I see, I understand now the reason why I had to switch back the Z scale from 0 to 1 to make it work on a Sphere, which was my inital intention with that plane. If I had try that  on a sphere instead, I would have never ask that question x) but I'm glad I did, you guys are amazing thank you !