Why does my Geometry Node setup seem to ignore my Noise Texture?
I'm currently trying to create an effect where a collection of plants are scattered across a "field" in clumps. I'm trying to drive those clumps using a Noise Texture, and while it seems I can control how many plants are scattered across my scene, I cannot seem to get them to follow the Noise Texture. Here's my setup:

And for reference, here's what the geometry currently looks like. I set the duplicated the noise texture and set it as the plane's material so I could compare the distribution of the Collection to the Noise Texture visually.

As you can see, the plant distribution seems to be completely ignoring the Noise Texture. I'm sure I've done something wrong, but I don't know what! I'm using Blender 4.1.1, Windows 11.
EDIT: What I am trying to achieve specifically is that I would like to use the Noise Texture to drive WHERE the plants appear. So using the Texture in the second image as an example, ideally the plants should appear in the black parts and not at all in the white parts.
EDIT 2: It seemed that adding a Position, Bounding Box and Map Range node allowed me to get the results that I was looking for. The solution for me was found on this post Texture Coordinate Node for Geometry Nodes?
Thanks everyone!

This question is similar to: Using an image node as Point Distribute density in Geometry Nodes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for linking that post @Crantisz. I have taken a look at their setup and have followed the steps, but I have not been able to replicate the same effects. Currently the Noise Texture is still not driving the location of the Collection.

Look also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273778/how-can-i-use-the-same-noise-texture-in-shader-editor-to-distribute-points-with

@quellenform Thank you for linking that post. I tried out the setup and it worked! I appreciate all the prompt and useful help.

I think the issue is what quellenform mentioned. When you use a noise texture in a shader it uses Generated coordinates which use local space and are normalized from 0-1.
When used in geometry nodes they use unbound local space. So they aren't going to line up.
Im gonna guess this is a scaling issue and the holes youve made are tiny. You need to adjust the scale of the noise. Make it like .2, remove your coloramp node and then slide the threshold value from 0-1. You should see something happen
